# Edit text with editable and non editable hint/text - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I saw dasher messanger using edit text with some area editable and others fixed - http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/04556wl302. Not sure how we can draw it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entire thing is not an Edit Text, Its a layout. You can acheive that effect as follows.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/round_border">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Enter your amount"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

> @drawable/round_border is a drawable you should keep in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners android:radius="5dp"/>
<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks. It is one way of looking at that. I was looking into more of one view (custom view) since there can be n such views.